# Render Isomorphic content fetched over AJAX

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm not new to React but not the most seasoned developer here either. Right now I'm burrowing myself in complex personal projects in order to learn all about what react has to offer and to get better at it.

I've hit a wall right now and I'd like to get some opinions on how to solve this issue:

I have a news-feed in my React+Redux app. It loads its content using FetchAPI and renders the content after that, like so:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
    getNews() // Populates redux store (this.props.news)
},

render: function() {
    if (!this.props.news.title) return <span>Loading...</span>
    return (
        <div className="news">
            <div className="title">{this.props.news.title}</div>
            <div className="image" style={this.style()}></div>
            <div className="body">{this.props.news.body}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This works just fine for a SPA but the problem arises when we try to render this isomorphic.

I use pollyfill so the node server understands the FetchAPI. When i load '/news' directly the node server has gotten the ajax data and renders the news page with the article preloaded. The client however complains about 'checksum was invalid.' which means it tried to render before it got the response.

I have read up on this issue and a lot of people think that for a SPA we need to show a 'Loading...' to improve UX. A lot of people also think we need to render this due to SEO & NON-JS reasons. I'd like to wait for the data on the server but not on the client. I'd also likt it if i did not get this problem with invalid checksums on page load where content is loaded asynchronously.

How should I go about this? I'd like not to write any

```
if (server) {wait()} else {renderLoading()}
```

Comment: use *React.renderComponent()*

Comment: Sorry, @HarpreetSingh. That does not answer my question at all.
Also last time I looked that function was renamed to ReactDOM.render()

Comment: This might help https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/blob/master/app/Router.js#L48. It's for redux but the mechanics are the same for a fetch - static method(s) which return Promises.

Comment: @DominicTobias I see what you are getting at but the issue is that the server I have already fetches AJAX before rendering and I'd like it to be asynch in the client unless it's the first page I load. Maybe I should try to transfer the servers state to the client on initial load?

Comment: In redux it's up to the action to decide whether it needs to fetch or not - so I just do in componentDidMount - `User.readyOnActions(this.props.dispatch, this.props.params);` (and it won't be refetched if the store already has the info)

Comment: @DominicTobias But don't that mean that i will no longer be able to fetch the same data asynchronously? If the user starts at another page I'd still like to show the "Loading..." text

Comment: @DominicTobias Using the example you linked with some help from reddit I managed to get it all to work, thank you! If you'd like to submit an answer I'd happily mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Snabel that's alright glad you got something working :)